# Check if file exists with environmental variable in path (Win platform)

Tags: java, file, environment-variables

I have to check if some application exists in different places to run-up `ProcessBuilder` on Windows. The problem is I need to use enviromental variable which is not resolved until I run the `cmd.exe`. I have something like this non working code.

```
private static final String WIN_APP = "%USERPROFILE%/AppData/Local/App/app.exe";
...
File f1 = new File(WIN_APP);
if(f1.exists()) { ... };
...
```

Do you have any hints? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't expect value of environment variable `userprofile` directly in the `WIN_APP` variable value.

You should make an explicit call to `System.getenv("userprofile")` and shall be used with other text of the said variable to work.

```
String userProfile = System.getenv("userProfile");

// hoping user profile is not null
String Win_App = userProfile + "/AppData/Local/App/app.exe";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
private static final String WIN_APP =
       System.getenv("userprofile") + "/AppData/Local/App/app.exe";
...
```